# Reattach Console Session in a Windows Server machine

Tags: windows

In a Windows Server machine (such as Windows Server 2008), there can be a console session and many more RDP sessions. But sometimes the console session get detached from the server. From a service running on the same server machine I want to reattach the console session if it's detached.

I searched for days but no luck yet. Please help me on how to do it. I have tested this scenario with 'LogMeIn free' and it successfully reattach the console.

Answer (score 0):

Create a shortcut, and use the target as below:

%systemroot%\system32\mstsc.exe /admin /v:SERVER_ADDRESS

use /admin parameter will always allow you to connect to console

Comment: Hi Gekowa,
I tried your option. It shows the console desktop, but it doesn't reattach or activate the console session. It's been shown as another RDP session in the task manager->users. What I want is to reattach/activate the console session.

Comment: as far as i tried, this RDP connection will show the console desktop. I used to find some other services such as TeamViewer, VNC, or LogMeIn, and I finally use this method.